# How to filter select options with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter the options inside a select box `person` based on the value selected in another select box `invoice_project_id`:

```
<select id="invoice_project_id">
  <option value="1">Project A</option>
  <option value="2">Project B</option>
  <option value="3">Project C</option>
</select>

<select id="person">
  <option data-project_ids="[1,2]">Spencer, Eve</option>
  <option data-project_ids="[3]">Goodwin, Alisha</option>
  <option data-project_ids="[]">Emard, Tito</option>
  <option data-project_ids="[2,3]">Bergstrom, Damien</option>
</select>
```

This is the jQuery I've got so far:

```
function filterOption(id) {
  return $('#person option').filter(function () {
    return $.inArray(id, $(this).data('project_ids')) > -1
  });
}

$('#invoice_project_id').on('change', function() {
  var project = $('#invoice_project_id :selected').val();   
  var options = filterOption(parseInt(project));
  if (options) {
    return $('#person').html(options);
  } else {
    return $('#person').empty();
  }
});
```

The function `filterOption()` was kindly provided by [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) on this forum, however can't manage to integrate it into my code due to my lack of experience in jQuery.

Can anybody help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try: `var options = filterOption(parseInt(project));`

Comment: @KhanhTO: Yes, of course. Sorry, I actually had that before. Just added it.

Answer (score 2):

Since `filterOption` function returns a jQuery collection you can hide the options and call the `.show()` on the returned collection:

```
$('#invoice_project_id').on('change', function() {
   var project = $('#invoice_project_id').val(); 
   $('#person option').hide();
   filterOption(+project).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M3Xga/

Please note that not all browsers handle showing/hiding the `option` elements. Alternatively you can disable/enable the options by modifying `disabled` properties:

```
$('#person option').prop('disabled', true);
filterOption(+project).prop('disabled', false)
                      .first()
                      .prop('selected', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PjHc6/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot but I must be missing something because your fiddle doesn't work in my browser (Safari).

Comment: @Tintin81 Yes, it won't work in all the browsers, can you use `disabled` property instead?

Comment: @BlackSheep: No, disabling options just greys them out which is not what I want in this particular case. Your first solution looks perfect to me however it doesn't work at all in Safari and has some weaknesses in other (good) browsers too.

Comment: could you please explain me what would that     return $('#person option').filter(function () {
        return $.inArray(id, $(this).data('project_ids')) > -1
    }); return ?

Comment: @Tintin81 That's how browsers handle this. You can either use custom select boxes (_there are many plugins that you can use_) or create a hidden select, clone the matching options from it and then append them to the main select.

Comment: @яша The `filter()` function only returns the elements that match the condition, `false` removes the element and `true` adds it to the filtered collection (_a jQuery collection_).